# Any way for a 3rd-level summoner to cast Lesser Restore Eidolon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, healing, summoner

I have been hit with spell that damaged my eidolon for −2 strength ability.  I don't get *restore eidolon, lesser* until I level up to level 4 and get 2nd level spells.  Is there a way to be able to temporarily "borrow" from or take one spell from my 2nd level spell list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48745/discussion-between-kryan-and-rowley-falconforge).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scroll or wand would get you want to want, limited-use magic (See your local magic shop today!).

Other than that, no.

IIRC there is a Wizard feat/archetype that gets access to a single 2nd level spell faster, but I don't think it applies to a Summoner.

Comment: Yes currently adventuring - just finished combat with goblins.  Hear more coming.  Magic shop - not likely nearby.

Answer (score 6):

### Ability damage can be healed naturally.

All your eidolon needs to do is rest.
They will recover 1 point of each [Ability Damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Ability-Score-Damage) taken per day of rest.

> Unless otherwise noted, damage to your ability scores is healed at the rate of 1 per day to each ability score that has been damaged. Ability damage can be healed through the use of spells, such as lesser restoration.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case.  RAW state that "The eidolon does not heal naturally."  http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner.  Furthermore, eidolons when resummoned, "the eidolon hit points are unchanged from the last time it was dismissed or banished." Unless it is killed.  So the natural healing of rest does not apply AND ability damage although not specifically stated would likely be treated same as hit points.  Therefore the restore eidolon lesser spell is needed - to invoke lesser restoration for the eidolon.

Comment: You are correct. However, from a raw reading, this healing is not natural healing. And the eidolon does not say that ability damage cannot be healed over time.

Comment: The consensus is that ability damage is healed by natural healing, but there are many exceptions on the rules that will increase your natural healing, but not affect ability damage healing in any way (like fast healing or regeneration). That is more of a mechanical way to balance the class than anything, you should ask what your GM thinks about it.

Comment: Another example is the Fatigued condition, if an eidolon cannot "rest", then they cannot remove the Fatigued condition in any way other than magical healing.